# Remove Checkbox for the django image field

Tags: python, django, image, checkbox

I have a model like below

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=56)
    picture = ImageField(upload_to='/max/')
```

So when editing the Book model from templates like below

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'edit_book' book_id %}" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{book_form.name}}
   {{book_form.picture}}
</form>
```

if the book record already has an image an extra html checkbox has been

```
    Currently: 
<a href="/media/product138ba6ccf0d1408d968577fa7648e0ea/assets/bubble.png">media/product138ba6ccf0d1408d968577fa7648e0ea/assets/bubble.png</a>

 <input id="picture-clear_id" name="picture-clear" type="checkbox" /> <label for="picture-clear_id">Clear</label><br />Change: 

<input id="selectedFile" name="picture" type="file" />
```

So if the book has an image already when it has been created, it also has some `checkbox` and label before it so how to avoid that checkbox ?

**Edit**

**forms.py**

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    super(BookForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['picture'].widget.attrs = {'id':'selectedFile'}
```

Comment: Could you show your ModelForm class?

Comment: I have edited my question above please have a look at it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little surprised to be honest, because what you describe looks like [`ClearableFileInput` widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#clearablefileinput), while [according to the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#filefield), it is [`FileInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#fileinput) that is used as a default widget.

Still. Try explicitly choosing `FileInput`:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, FileInput

class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        widgets = {
            'picture': FileInput(),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BookForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['picture'].widget.attrs = {'id':'selectedFile'}
```

**Update:** I'm not surprised anymore. I investigated the issue, and it turned out there simply was a mistake in Django Docs, [now corrected](https://github.com/django/django/commit/70e61310d690fab109c5298e41783db61306f831). `ClearableFileInput` is the default widget, so you need to set `FileInput` explicitly, as shown above.